# Android FusedLocationAPI GPS accuracy seems incorrect

Tags: android, gps, fusedlocationproviderapi

I am writing a simple Android application that captures a user's location.

I am using the FusedLocationAPI to provide the position.

```
  mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
            .setInterval(5000)
            .setFastestInterval(5000);
```

When the user presses a button, the app will first check the last known location. If this is less than one minute old and has an accuracy of < 50m, the location is used. If not, the app requests location updates until a position is received with an accuracy of < 50m. The app then stop requesting updates, to help preserve battery.

This works very well 99% of the time. However, in testing, a situation arose where two readings were taken for the same position, but there is a distance of 110m between the coordinates reported. I'm trying to understand why.

Reading #1: Taken at 10:46 with an accuracy of 36m.

Reading #2: Taken at 13:27 with an accuracy of 26m.

The user is in the same location (within about 2m). I would assume that, with their position at the edge of the accuracy, there could only be a maximum of 52m distance between the points. I don't know why it's 110m

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not what accuracy figure means. Quoting from google docs:

> We define accuracy as the radius of 68% confidence. In other words, if
>   you draw a circle centered at this location's latitude and longitude,
>   and with a radius equal to the accuracy, then **there is a 68%
>   probability** that the true location is inside the circle.
>
> In statistical terms, it is assumed that location errors are random
>   with a normal distribution, so the 68% confidence circle represents
>   one standard deviation. Note that in practice, location errors do not
>   always follow such a simple distribution.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getAccuracy

Comment: I didn't see that at all, so thanks for pasting it here. It's not really accuracy then, more probability of correctness. I've updated my app to use a longer time window when acquiring a fix and it has a lower discrimination threshold too and this seems to have solved my issues. Thx